Flutter - CallKit Incoming not working in ios when app is in terminated
To implement call kit I used flutter_callkit_incoming package and use local notification to trigger call kit.
This is working in Android when app is in the foreground or background, but it's not working in iOS in the background.
Here are the steps which I followed for setup.
On flutter : https://github.com/hiennguyen92/flutter_callkit_incoming/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart
On app delegate :  https://github.com/hiennguyen92/flutter_callkit_incoming/blob/master/example/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift
And for iOS steup: https://github.com/hiennguyen92/flutter_callkit_incoming/blob/master/PUSHKIT.md
// listen to notification in background and trigger call kit.
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  debugPrint("-----[FIREBASE-BACK]------><><>Handling a background message: ${message.data}");
  if (message.data['topic'] == 'screen.sharing.invite') {
    showCallkitIncoming(data: message.data);
  }
}

Function implemention:
// Here is the full implementation of showCallKitIncoming function
Future<void> showCallkitIncoming({required Map<String?, dynamic> data}) async {
  CallKitParams params = CallKitParams(
    id: const Uuid().v4(),
    nameCaller: 'APP Screen Sharing Call',
    appName: 'APP Title',                 ///<<< this is also not working...
    avatar: data['senderImageUrl'],
    handle: data['senderName'],
    type: 0, // 0 for audio and 1 for video
    duration: 60000, //60 seconds
    textAccept: 'Accept',
    textDecline: 'Decline',
    missedCallNotification: const NotificationParams(
      showNotification: true,
      isShowCallback: false,
      subtitle: 'Missed call',
      callbackText: '',
    ),
    extra: <String, dynamic>{'guestRoomCode': data['guestRoomCode'], 'receiverName': data['receiverName']},
    headers: <String, dynamic>{},
    android: const AndroidParams(
      isShowLogo: true,
      textColor: "#ffffff",
      actionColor: '#dda088',
      backgroundColor: '#dda088',
      isShowCallID: true,
      isCustomNotification: true,
      isShowFullLockedScreen: true,
      isCustomSmallExNotification: true,
      ringtonePath: 'system_ringtone_default',
      incomingCallNotificationChannelName: 'screen_share_call',
      missedCallNotificationChannelName: "screen_share_miss_call",
    ),
    ios: const IOSParams(
      iconName: 'AppIcon',
      handleType: '',
      supportsVideo: true,
      maximumCallGroups: 2,
      maximumCallsPerCallGroup: 1,
      audioSessionMode: 'default',
      audioSessionActive: true,
      audioSessionPreferredSampleRate: 44100.0,
      audioSessionPreferredIOBufferDuration: 0.005,
      supportsDTMF: true,
      supportsHolding: true,
      supportsGrouping: false,
      supportsUngrouping: false,
      ringtonePath: 'system_ringtone_default',
    ),
  );
  await FlutterCallkitIncoming.showCallkitIncoming(params);
}

Getting Notification when app is killed but call kit not showing up.
Apart from this, I also want to how can I hide notification for this call only other notification need to show as usual.
Thanks in advance.

Are you sending a voip push to indicate an incoming call?  A standard push will not launch a terminated app.
